# How can I measure the frequency of access of an application or firmware to the disk?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I need to measure the frequency of access of an application ( or applications as part of the firmware) to the drive of an Android device. Is there any tool or methodology for obtaining such statistics ?

It seemed to me that this event is logged and it can be obtained from the logs using some construction that is approximately similar to `grep "event_marker" | wc-l`. But as far as I know, this event is logged very often and it is unlikely to occur in the logs.